# GridView with different layouts Android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I am working on a `gridview`, where it has 3 options named "small","medium","large" in the overflow, the grid sizes should be adjustable upon selecting anyone of the above 3 options, I don't find a solution to load them as per the option selected.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you explain what is your real problem

Comment: where is the issue ?

Comment: @Jigs, Sree I meant that the grid item size should vary based on the option selected on the menu. the options are small, medium & large.

Comment: Finally solved it, by using Dynamic GirdView a third party library